# Running multiple scanner at one time

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have two scanner that scans for currency and weight from external text file. 1st scanner for Currency and 2nd scanner for Weight. The problem here is, only the top scanner works, second scanner does not provide any output. How can i reset the 2nd scanner to start reading from top of file once 1st scanner have finish scanning and give output. Below are the 2 scanners

**Scanner for Currency**

```
String sc[]= {myTextCount};
String value, currency; 
for(String ssc : sc){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(ssc);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) { 
        value = scan.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
        currency = scan.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
        try {
            float f = Float.valueOf(value.trim()).floatValue();
                for(int j = 0; j < currencyWords.length; j++) {
                    if ((currency).equals(currencyWords[j])) {
                        jTextArea2.append(f + currencyWords[j] + "-" +currencyFile + "\n"); 
                        currency = scan.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
                    } 
                }   
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            //System.err.println("NumberFormatExceptionsssss: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

Scanner for Weight

```
String s[]= {myTextCount};
String weight, unit; 
for(String ss : s){
Scanner scanC = new Scanner(ss);
    while (scanC.hasNextLine()) { 
        weight = scanC.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
        unit = scanC.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
        try {
            float f = Float.valueOf(weight.trim()).floatValue();
                for(int j = 0; j < weightWords.length; j++) {
                   if ((unit).equals(weightWords[j])) {
                      jTextArea2.append(f + weightWords[j] + "-" +weightFile + "\n"); 
                      unit = scanC.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
                   } 
                 }   
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            //System.err.println("NumberFormatExceptionsssss: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using break but still does not work. Only 1st scanner runs and second scanner does not run. Help me to show algorithm on how i can reset the scanners

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by joining both scanners.

```
String s[]= {myTextCount};
String weight, unit; 
for(String ss : s){
    Scanner scanC = new Scanner(ss);
    while (scanC.hasNextLine()) { 
        weight = scanC.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
        unit = scanC.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
        try {
            float f = Float.valueOf(weight.trim()).floatValue();
                for(int j = 0; j < weightWords.length; j++) {
                    for(int g = 0; g < currencyWords.length; g++) {
                        if ((unit).equals(weightWords[j])) {
                            jTextArea2.append(f + weightWords[j] + "-" +weightFile + "\n"); 
                            unit = scanC.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
                        } scanC.reset();
                        if ((unit).equals(currencyWords[g])) {
                            jTextArea2.append(f + currencyWords[g] + "-" +currencyFile + "\n"); 
                            unit = scanC.next();//scan.next("\\w+");
                        }scanC.reset();
                    }
                }   
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            //System.err.println("NumberFormatExceptionsssss: " + nfe.getMessage());
        } 
}  scanC.close();
}
```